# Filter all columns in Python, Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have made a small `db.Model` and I want to search all columns of `db.Model` for some word.

I have tried doing this on my own but it wont work:

```
Uni.filter("* =", word)

db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Uni WHERE *=:1", word)
```

I am new to Python and Models.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that.

You might try using the new [full-text search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/).

Comment: or review your data model.  If you are looking for a term in all properties of your model it suggests to me you data model doesn't suit your application.